# Woocommerce conditional tag for product loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a function for Woocommerce and I need to only have it on all product archives including wherever products are displayed in the loop, i.e. Related products, up-sells etc.

I tried is_shop() but then the function does not get applied to the related products on the single product pages, the same goes for is_archive(). What conditional tag is there to include products wherever they are displayed in the loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
  You can Try Like this inside the loop.

    global $woocommerce_loop;
    
    if ( is_product() && $woocommerce_loop['name'] == 'related' ) {
    
    }
```

Comment: I do't only want it for the related products, it should be everywhere where products are displayed in the grid, for example also if a Woo shortcode for products is used.

Comment: Please check this url. Possibly you can find your answer here.
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-conditional-logic-ultimate-php-guide/

Comment: I had checked this site, it did not include any conditional tags that solve my problem.